# Como puedo asignarle a una variable un valor que esta en un DIV

Tags: javascript, php, css

Tengo el siguiente problema, JS no me toma lo que está dentro de unos DIV con el ID, sí yo agrego los numeros manualmente en un **CONST HORARIO** me lo toma, pero al agregarle la variable no me lo toma.

¿Qué me faltaría para que funcione?

Codigo Javascript

```javascript
function Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos() {
    /*Referencia al div contenedor general*/
    mDiv = document.getElementById('resultados');
    /*variables que contienen los horarios*/
    /*turno mañana*/
    /*toma lo que esta en el DIV tmdesde*/
    mtminicio = document.getElementById('tmdesde').innerHTML
    /*toma lo que esta en el DIV tmhasta*/
    mtmfin = document.getElementById('tmhasta').innerHTML
    /*turno tarde*/
    /*toma lo que esta en el DIV ttdesde*/
    ttminicio = document.getElementById('ttdesde').innerHTML
    /*toma lo que esta en el DIV tthasta*/
    ttmfin = document.getElementById('tthasta').innerHTML
    /*cada tantos minutos de atencion*/
    /*toma lo que esta en el DIV cada*/
    mcada = document.getElementById('cada').innerHTML
    /*Fragmento para ir agregando cada elemento*/
    var mFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


    const Horario = {
        dia: {
            inicio: mtminicio,
            fin: mtmfin
        },
        tarde: {
            inicio: ttminicio,
            fin: ttmfin
        },
        cada: mcada,
    };
    var now = new Date();
    var inicial = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.inicio, 0, 0, 0);
    var final = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), Horario.dia.fin, 0, 0, 0);
    /*Variable para identificar cada id de los p*/
    var i = 1;
    for (var f = inicial; f <= final; f.setMinutes(f.getMinutes() + Horario.cada)) {
        let hora = ("0" + String(f.getHours())).slice(-2); //slice para dar
        // formato de 2 digitos
        let minutos = ("0" + String(f.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
        /*Creamos un elemento p*/
        var mP = document.createElement("p");
        /*Establecemos su id con el valor de i y aumentamos i en 1*/
        mP.setAttribute("id", `p${i++}`);
        /*Le agregamos el contenido de forma segura*/
        mP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${hora}:${minutos}`));
        /*Lo agregamos al fragmento*/
        mFragment.appendChild(mP);
        
    }
    /*Finalmente, agregamos el fragmento al div contenedor*/

    mDiv.appendChild(mFragment);
}
```

Código HTML

```
                 <div id="resultados" class="mb-6"></div>
```

Añado codigo HTML donde figura los horarios

```
                             <?php 
                            $objCon = new Conexion();
                            $conexion = $objCon->conectar();
                            $sql = "SELECT nombre, tmdesde, tmhasta, 
                            ttdesde, tthasta, cada 
                            FROM lunes WHERE nombre = 'JULIO ANDRES'";
                            $resultadolunes = mysqli_query($conexion, 
                             $sql); 
                             while($lunes = 
                             mysqli_fetch_array($resultadolunes)) {
                             ?> 
                        <button type="button" 
                          onclick="Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos()"> 
                         ver</button>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turno Mañana </h4>'?> 
                        </div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tmdesde"> <?php echo 
                         $lunes['tmdesde']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tmhasta"> <?php echo 
                         $lunes['tmhasta']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turno Tarde </h4>'?> 
                        </div>
                        <div> <h4 id="ttdesde"> <?php echo 
                        $lunes['ttdesde']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <h4 id="tthasta"> <?php echo 
                         $lunes['tthasta']?> </h4></div>
                        <div> <?php echo '<h4> Turnos cada </h4>'?> 
                        </div>
                        <div> <h4 id="cada"> <?php echo $lunes['cada']?> 
                         </h2></div>
                        <?php 
                         }
                         ?>
```

Comment: Todo parece bien, revisaste la consola a ver si te sale algun error???

Comment: no sale nada por consola y en los div tengo numeros como DE 9 a 13 y 16 a 20

Comment: ok sera posible que agregues el formulario (html)???

Comment: el codigo tienes que agregarlo en la pregunta usa el boton editar...

Comment: Lo siento.!!! ahi lo edite...gracias

Comment: mira el primer problema que detecto es que en tu html que esta dentro de un bucle usas como referencia ID, de casualidad sabes que no puedes repetir los atributos id en html???

Comment: no sabia....pero los nombres ID no están repetidos, como se podría solucionar?

Comment: ya te respondo...

Comment: Referencia acerca del ID: [El atributo global id define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: si alguna de las respuesta que te dieron responde tu duda recuerda marcarla como respondida/resuelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de solicitarte que agregaras el `HTML`, he podido evaluar que tu problema esta asociado a el codigo `HTML` que generas desde `PHP`.

Esto se debe a que en `HTML` no se puede utilizar el mismo `valor` del `atributo` `ID` en multiples elementos:

por ejemplo, Esto seria un error:

```
<?php 
while($lunes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadolunes)) { ?> 
    <!-- ELEMENTOS DUPLICADOS -->
    <button type="button" onclick="Obtenerhorariosdesdemedicos()">ver</button> 
    <div> <h4 id="tmdesde"> <?php echo $lunes['tmdesde']?> </h4></div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

el segundo Boton que se genere, no se le asignara el evento o no funcionara correctamente.

lo correcto seria, idetinficar cada input mediante un id que se paresca pero no sea igual o implementar el atributo: `class` o `name` con el metodo [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Tambien puedes implementar una la delegacion de eventos, [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) y mesclarlo con el `querySelector` anterior evitando usar el onclick dentro del boton.

Entonces lo ideal seria implementar en `querySelector`  algo como:

- `[name^='someName']` coincidirá con todos los `name` que comiencen con someName.
- `[name$='someName']` coincidirá con todos los `name` que terminan en someName.
- `[name*='someName']` coincidirá con todos los `name` que contengan someName.

Si está buscando el atributo de `class`, simplemente sustituya el `name` con el `class`.

Comment: gracias por tu aporte...!!!!

Comment: pero entendiste cual es el problema??? y como se soluciona???

Comment: me falta mucho conocimiento todavía y por ahí no me doy cuenta pero buscando y pidiendo ayuda voy forjando mi conocimiento...igual me falta un monton. en fin...con el queryselector tendría que seleccionar el NAME del objeto INPUT (y nó de un DIV) y traer los datos...algo asi?

Comment: si pero con ese puede selecionar tambien al div pero utilizando patrones... dejame agregarlo.

Comment: perfecto....toda ayuda es muy util y agradecido por ello.